# ActiveAndroid app autocloses when run on Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, activeandroid

I have an app developed with Android Studio and Gradle. The app uses ActiveAndroid. The app works perfectly on 3.0 and up. When run on a Gingerbread device it just opens, white screen, and then closes automatically. The only clue given in the logcat when app is run is the following:

```
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 195K, 41% free 3988K/6663K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 0ms+0ms
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$1; interface 1088 'Landroid/view/ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowAttachListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$1;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$2; interface 1089 'Landroid/view/ViewTreeObserver$OnWindowFocusChangeListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2$2;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2; interface 180 'Landroid/media/RemoteControlClient$OnGetPlaybackPositionListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/media/TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2; interface 224 'Landroid/os/Parcelable$ClassLoaderCreator;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/os/ParcelableCompatCreatorHoneycombMR2;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$1; (241)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$1;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1$1; interface 207 'Landroid/os/CancellationSignal$OnCancelListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2$1$1;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2; (241)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$2;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1; (1064)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatIcs$1;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1; (1064)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/AccessibilityDelegateCompatJellyBean$1;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompatIcs$OnActionExpandListenerWrapper; interface 1056 'Landroid/view/MenuItem$OnActionExpandListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompatIcs$OnActionExpandListenerWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs$1; interface 1096 'Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager$AccessibilityStateChangeListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerCompatIcs$1;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1; (1099)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatJellyBean$1;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatKitKat$1; (1099)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeProviderCompatKitKat$1;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$1; interface 1178 'Landroid/widget/SearchView$OnQueryTextListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$1;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$2; interface 1177 'Landroid/widget/SearchView$OnCloseListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatHoneycomb$2;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView; (1179)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompatIcs$MySearchView;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplHC$CallbackWrapper; interface 1031 'Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplHC$CallbackWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS$OnMenuVisibilityListenerWrapper; interface 22 'Landroid/app/ActionBar$OnMenuVisibilityListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS$OnMenuVisibilityListenerWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS$OnNavigationListenerWrapper; interface 23 'Landroid/app/ActionBar$OnNavigationListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS$OnNavigationListenerWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/ActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper; interface 1031 'Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/ActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$ActionProviderWrapper; (1034)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$ActionProviderWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$CollapsibleActionViewWrapper; interface 1035 'Landroid/view/CollapsibleActionView;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$CollapsibleActionViewWrapper;' failed
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 713K, 44% free 4167K/7431K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 1ms+0ms
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5; interface 1072 'Landroid/view/View$OnLayoutChangeListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/widget/SearchView$5;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/crashlytics/android/internal/G; interface 34 'Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/crashlytics/android/internal/G;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/crashlytics/android/internal/x; interface 34 'Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/crashlytics/android/internal/x;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics$b; interface 34 'Landroid/app/Application$ActivityLifecycleCallbacks;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics$b;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ErrorDialogFragment; (37)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/ErrorDialogFragment;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager$e; interface 61 'Landroid/content/ComponentCallbacks2;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/images/ImageManager$e;' failed
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 804K, 44% free 4332K/7687K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 1ms+0ms
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment; (38)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaFragment; (38)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanoramaFragment;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/tagmanager/bb$1; (1024)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/tagmanager/bb$1;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/WalletFragment; (38)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/wallet/fragment/WalletFragment;' failed
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 884K, 43% free 4700K/8135K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 0ms+0ms
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS$TabWrapper; interface 25 'Landroid/app/ActionBar$TabListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBarImplICS$TabWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/ActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper; interface 1031 'Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/ActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/ActionModeWrapperJB$CallbackWrapper; (829)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/ActionModeWrapperJB$CallbackWrapper;' failed
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$OnActionExpandListenerWrapper; interface 1056 'Landroid/view/MenuItem$OnActionExpandListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$OnActionExpandListenerWrapper;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$ActionProviderWrapper; (1034)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperICS$ActionProviderWrapper;' failed
W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperJB$ActionProviderWrapperJB; (865)
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Landroid/support/v7/internal/view/menu/MenuItemWrapperJB$ActionProviderWrapperJB;' failed
D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Lcom/google/android/gms/games/internal/IGamesService$Stub; has 151 unimplemented (abstract) methods
I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/games/internal/PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1; interface 1067 'Landroid/view/View$OnAttachStateChangeListener;'
W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/games/internal/PopupManager$PopupManagerHCMR1;' failed
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 969K, 42% free 4870K/8391K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 1ms+0ms
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 992K, 42% free 5039K/8583K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 1ms+0ms
```

My gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir name: 'localRepository', dirs: 'libs-aar'
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '16.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include:'lottusse_android.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
    compile 'drag-sort-listview:drag-sort-listview:@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include:'ActiveAndroid.jar')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    aaptOptions.useAaptPngCruncher = true

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 163
        versionName "1.1.1"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

I have tried on a low-end Samsung phone running Gingerbread and also on a Gennymotion emulator running 2.3.7. After debugging I found that the app hangs when performing the scanForModel method inside the ActiveAndroid.initialize method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround for this issue? Having a similar problem with scanForModelClasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't  provide model classes manually ActiveAndroid will automatically search for it in .dex file when app starts. 
That can consume large amount of memory.

You add model classes in Activity or in manifest.

More here:

[How to disable scanning for model in Activeandroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907037/how-to-disable-scanning-for-model-in-activeandroid)